# What tool can I use to test the speed of my network

Tags: networking

I would like to find a tool to test the network bandwidth between 2 servers. Also statistics about latency and package reliability would be nice.

I have shell access to both servers, but no root access. I can run open some high numbered port. The machines are running CentOS.

I have tried to test speeds with scp, but I think what I get to see is the disk write speeds instead of the network speed.

Answer (score 9):

I recommend using iPerf - http://sourceforge.net/projects/iperf/

Runs as a client and a server with a good number of options for traffic types.

Answer (score 3):

SSH is not a good idea as it adds extra overhead. If your servers have SATA drives and Gigabit Network connection then, hard drives could be a bottleneck. If you have SAS drives and RAID controller w/ cache, it won't. iPerf is a good solution, and the other simple solution is ftp.
You can also use iptraf or nload to watch your bandwitch usage.

Answer (score 1):

I like this solution: [Use netcat to test network speed](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/forums/showthread.php/18736-Use-netcat-to-test-network-speed)

It only requires netcat which is typically installed by default with most Linux distributions.

Comment: When you link to another forum or blogpost, please add some details in your answer from that link to make sure your answer is still good even if the linked site goes down.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you have ssh servers set-up on these machines and ofcourse that ping is installed by default...

You should be able to test the speed by transferring some large files between these using
[ssh server "cat remote_file" > local_file]

And package reliability just by using [ping server]

Comment: I don't think I'll get network speeds here, but the disk writing speeds (the network is very high-end). I would like to factor out any disk properties.

Comment: Also, SSH would have extra overhead of compression. Depending on available resources of your system, this may increase or reduce the speed.

Comment: Small google for "linux network speed test" later maybe http://www.edugeek.net/forums/networks/202-point-point-network-speed-test-tools.html might help